# My model is drawn wrong in 3d

Tags: opengl, c++

I'm learning OpenGL and now after I made everything I needed, I started with 3D, my first problem is that my mesh doesn't draw like I intended...[image]

Here's my rectangle (uses GL_TRIANGLES):

```
std::vector<GLfloat> Vpos =
{
    0.5, 0.5, //0.0,
    0.5, -0.5, //0.0,
    -0.5, -0.5, //0.0
    - 0.5, -0.5, //0.0
    - 0.5, 0.5, //0.0,
    0.5, 0.5, //0.0
};//comms are the 3d version
```

And here I draw my array:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, verNum / 2); //it is binded with vertex array, I use shaders
```

And my fragment shader is:

```
#version 330

in vec2 passTextureCoords;

out vec4 outColor;

uniform sampler2D ourTexture;

void main()
{
    outColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0);// texture(ourTexture, passTextureCoords); I don't have a texture so I use a lightgreen for debug proposes
}
```

Also my vertex shader:

```
#version 330

layout (location=0) in vec3 inVertPos;
layout (location=1) in vec2 inTexCoords;

out vec2 passTextureCoords;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(inVertPos.x, inVertPos.y, inVertPos.z, 1.0);
    passTextureCoords = inTexCoords;
}
```

Thanks for help by now, I pretty sure that I missed something small but important.

Comment: First of all, you don't have a projection matrix, it's needed if you want to draw 3d. Second: the z coordinate of some of your vertices is negative, so they won't render

Comment: Do you have depth testing turned on? If so, did you clear your depth buffer?

Comment: @user1118321 yes you need also to enable DEPTH_TESTING using glEnable(). Here is a great website from where you can read a bit more about Opengl theory: https://learnopengl.com

Answer (score 1):

1) When you comment in or out elements of your `Vpos`, it changes the stride length of your inVertPos attribute. It looks like the stride is wrong and the zeros for the Z are getting into your X/Y coordinates. I strongly suspect that your stride is still being calculated incorrectly, based on the points being rendered in your screenshot (notice they match exactly my demo of "incorrect code" with a bad stride of `8`)

2) Your `Vpos` vector is missing some commas. This also breaks your square.

```
// this vector only has one element in it!
vector<float> demo = { 
   0.0
   - 1.0
};
```

```js
cv.width = document.body.clientWidth;
cv.height= document.body.clientHeight;

var gl = cv.getContext('webgl')
var frag = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(frag, 'void main() { gl_FragColor = vec4(1); }');
gl.compileShader(frag);
var vert = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(vert, `
attribute vec3 pos;
void main() { gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1); }`);
gl.compileShader(vert);
var prog = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(prog, vert);
gl.attachShader(prog, frag);
gl.linkProgram(prog);
gl.useProgram(prog);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
var buf = gl.createBuffer();

// correct
var verts = [  
    0.5,  0.5,  0.0,
    0.5, -0.5,  0.0,
    -0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
    - 0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
    - 0.5, 0.5, 0.0,
    0.5, 0.5,   0.0,
    ];
gl.viewport(0, 0, cv.width / 2,cv.height);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buf);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(verts), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 12, 0);   
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, verts.length / 3);
// incorrect
var verts = [  
    0.5,  0.5,  0.0,
    0.5, -0.5,  0.0,
    -0.5, -0.5, 0.0
    - 0.5, -0.5, 0.0
    - 0.5, 0.5, 0.0,
    0.5, 0.5,   0.0,
    ];
gl.viewport(cv.width / 2, 0, cv.width / 2,cv.height);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buf);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(verts), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 8, 0);   
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, verts.length / 3);
```

```css
#cv { background:#59e; width:100%; height:400px; }
```

```html
(left: correct. right: incorrect)
<canvas id=cv>
```

Comment: when I go 3d I switch this line glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, verNum / 2); with glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, verNum / 3);

Comment: But where are you calling glVertexAttribPointer?

Comment: glVertexAttribPointer(m_count, dimen, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)0);
 glEnableVertexAttribArray(m_count++);

Comment: this is in AdVbo function

Comment: and dimen is set to 3?

Comment: yes, I made a value, and used like this:is3D ? 3 : 2

Comment: This question has been bumped again -- did you ever resolve the issue? FWIW, it still seems like the vertex attrib stride is off, so that consecutive x/y values are picking up values intended for your Z coordinate. You could try manually setting a stride size of 12 instead of 0 in your glVertexAttribPointer call to help narrow down the problem.

Comment: Solved, and made it even better, with structs